# HttpWebRequest with basic auth always returns fail to create SSL/TLS channel

Tags: c#, https, rest

I'm trying to connect my local program to a Woocommerce RestAPI site through https and basic auth. I can connect via Insomnia to the site and works fine with these details.

In code, however, something is missing. I'm already forcing TLS1.2, the keys in the header info match what Insomnia generates, I just can't get it going... I know it's something obvious I've missed!

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://mytestwebsite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?sku=CSB4X4");

string encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes("ck_..." + ":" + "cs_..."));

req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
            
req.Method = "GET";
req.Accept = "*/*";
req.ContentType = "application/json";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

The error crops up on the very last line when trying to pull the response from the request. "System.Net.WebException: 'The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

I've tried logging the system.net items but nothing interesting jumps out at me.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a machine-specific issue rather than the code.